# Is it harmful to touch/inhale soaked/liquid printer ink?

Tags: eye, inhalation, skin-absorption

I have been printing a lot of work last night, but I accidentally placed my printed stack of paper (5 pages back to back filled printer ink) on top of a shelf below my air conditioner, next to me and went to sleep. (11pm)

I woke up at 7am with my bedsheet, face and neck soaked in water from the AC dripping above. But before it had reached me, it had bounced off my stack of paper which I use to print my work. The paper is now filled with yellow, red, blue clouds of ink spread across almost every page (black ink remains intact and visible on paper, not sure why).

I’m worried that my skin and eyes was in contact or that I may have inhaled the water-soaked printer ink for hours whilst I was asleep. I show no other symptoms except some minor eye irritation when I woke up, and have since taken a shower, done laundry, and moved my bed. Should I be worried about my health (eyesight, skin, respiration) as a result of this?

*I use a HP printer, and its cartridge ink is type 678, both black and tri-color.

Comment: We can't provide medical advice here (see the disclaimer in bold text in the upper right of your screen). Call a doctor, clinic, poison control center, or health department.